# Check if legit PayPal HTTP notify_url request

Tags: php, paypal

I've been searching for some information about PayPal header information but can't find anything.
I'm trying to find a secure way to verify if the post information sent to my notify_url is in fact from PayPal itself.

I've checked the `$_SERVER` variable and not a single key similar to `HTTP_PAYPAL` that could tell me that the request is from PayPal.

The only thing close was the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` but it can be easily modified:

```
'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'PayPal IPN ( https://www.paypal.com/ipn )'
```

How can I instruct PayPal to return me some custom headers to validate the request?

Comment: What is the POST back for? IPN notification?

Comment: yes it's IPN notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal allows you to query the full POST against their servers to verify a transaction. Essentially you take the POST, append `cmd=_notify-validate` to it and contact Paypal. Paypal will reply with `VERIFIED` or `UNVERIFIED`

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/